# How can I get a variable's initial value in Elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

In Emacs Lisp, is there a function to get the initial value of a symbol initilized by `defvar`? Like the `some-function` shown below:

```
(defvar var "initial value")
(setq var "changed value")
(some-function 'var)
=> "inital value"
```

Comment: Why would you expect there to be such a function?

Comment: @DavidThornley: `gnus-sum-thread-tree-root is a variable defined in \`gnus-sum.el'. Its value is "- " Original value was "> "`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Emacs doesn't remember the initial value. If you evaluate

```
(defvar var "initial value")
(setq var "changed value")
```

in the `*scratch*` buffer, `"initial value"` is no longer available, full stop.

If the `defvar` was performed in a loaded file, Emacs remembers where it's loaded from; `(symbol-file var 'defvar)` returns the file name, and you can get an the original expression that the variable was initialized with (but not the original value), assuming the file is still around.  This is also available via the command <kbd>M-x find-variable</kbd>.

Comment: Accepted. Luckly I found the desired variables are defined by `defcustom` instead of `defvar`. `defcustom` stores symbol's standard value in its property list.

Comment: -1 because this doesn't mention the `defcustom` symbol properties

Comment: @RichardHansen While this is indeed a useful side remark, the question is specifically about “a symbol initilized by `defvar`”. How can `defcustom` properties be relevant to a symbol initialized by `defvar`?

Comment: @Gilles:  Good point; now I wish I hadn't downvoted.  I had just the title in mind, which doesn't mention `defvar`.  However, mentioning `devcustom` would improve the quality of this answer...

Answer (score 16):

This is generally not possible (Emacs does not remember the original value), but there are some exceptions.

#### `defcustom` variables

Variables defined with `defcustom` and modified with the customization system get the original value, saved value, and customized-but-not-yet-saved value as properties:

```
(defcustom foo 0 "testing")
(custom-set-variables '(foo 1))
(setq foo 2)
(customize-mark-as-set 'foo)
(setq foo 3)

(car (get 'foo 'standard-value))   ;; evaluates to 0
(car (get 'foo 'saved-value))      ;; evaluates to 1
(car (get 'foo 'customized-value)) ;; evaluates to 2
foo                                ;; evaluates to 3
```

See the [Defining Customization Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variable-Definitions.html) section in the elisp manual, specifically the discussion above the documentation for the `custom-reevaluate-setting` function.

#### buffer-local variables

Buffer-local variables have a default (global) value and a buffer-local value that may differ from the global value.  You can use the `default-value` function to obtain the default value:

```
(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
(default-value 'indent-tabs-mode)  ;; evaluates to t
```

It is possible to change the default value, however, and Emacs won't remember the original default value:

```
(set-default 'indent-tabs-mode nil)
(default-value 'indent-tabs-mode)  ;; evaluates to nil
```

See the [Introduction to Buffer-Local Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Intro-to-Buffer_002dLocal.html) section in the elisp manual for more details.

Answer (score 5):

If the variable is set up to have [buffer local values](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer_002dLocal-Variables.html#Buffer_002dLocal-Variables) or [frame local values](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Frame_002dLocal-Variables.html#Frame_002dLocal-Variables), try:

```
(default-value 'var)
```

Though, if someone has used `setq-default` to change the default, you'll get the new one, and not the original that was set up via `defvar`.  From the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Default-Value.html):

> This function returns symbol's default
>   value. This is the value that is seen
>   in buffers and frames that do not have
>   their own values for this variable. If
>   symbol is not buffer-local, this is
>   equivalent to symbol-value (see [Accessing Variables](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Accessing-Variables.html#Accessing-Variables)).

Comment: `default-value` seems to return a buffer local variable's global value, not the initial value.

Comment: @pt True, I immediately jumped to buffer-locality in my head, I've updated the answer to reflect as much.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like @tao-peng found the answer himself here, but the full story is this:

A symbol created with `defvar` typically only has the value it is set to, as well as optionally a property list which at most usually has `variable-documentation` or maybe `risky-local-variable` set, e.g.:

```
> (symbol-plist 'load-path)
(risky-local-variable t variable-documentation -587478)
```

On the other hand, a symbol created with `defcustom` has a much longer `symbol-plist` including a `standard-value` property that you can get like this:

```
> (get 'package-archives 'standard-value)
((quote (("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))))
```

And as @trey-jackson notes, in the case of symbols that have buffer-local or frame-local values you can get the original value with:

```
> (setq foo "bar")
> (make-variable-buffer-local 'foo)
> (setq foo "baz")
> (default-value 'foo)
"bar"
> foo
"baz"
```

Answer (score 1):

Our solution:

```
;;;###autoload
(defun xorns-get-original-value (symbol)
  "Return SYMBOL's original value or nil if that is void."
  (if (boundp symbol)
    (eval (car (get symbol 'standard-value)))))
```