# How to set back to the original value interactively if a variable's value is changed?

Tags: vim, emacs, elisp

Sometimes the `defvar`/`defcustom` variable is changed by another expression in other elisp scripts with `setq` and the like, or they are altered by the directory/file local settings. Indeed I can use `describe-variable` to see its original value and then set it manually; however it is still a bit verbose.

In Vim, there is always a way to revert back to the **default** value of some variable by using `!`. And I believe that Emacs also has a way to achieve that goal.

So is there any simpler and interactive way to do so? Thanks.

**Update**: using `set-default` won't work. For instance, the *original* value of `goto-address-mail-face` is `italic` in goto-addr.el, and suppose I `(setq goto-address-mail-face 'link)` in `~/emacs.d/init.el`. However when I `(setq goto-address-mail-face (default-value 'goto-address-mail-face))` in the minibuffer, the result is still `link`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `defcustom` variables you can use the `M-x customize-variable` interface.

For `defvar`, I don't think the `INITVALUE` argument is remembered (and I don't think it is even evaluated in instances where the variable is already bound).

Variables can have "default" values, but this refers to the global value (as opposed to buffer-local bindings), and can of course be modified.

You can interactively set a buffer-local variable to its default value with `M-: (setq SYMBOL (default-value 'SYMBOL))`

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Default Value` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Yes, that is all exactly as I explained above. The "default" value is the *global* value, which can change: if a variable is not buffer-local, or otherwise locally bound, then `setq` sets the global value. If the variable was defined with `defvar`, then as far as I know there is no way to determine its `INITVALUE`.

Comment: But `goto-address-mail-face` is defined with `defcustom`, isn't it?

Comment: In which case you can use `M-x customize-variable`, as `defcustom` variables do remember their initial value in their symbol property list. You can observe this with `(get 'goto-address-mail-face 'standard-value)`. "default value" means the global value of the variable, no matter how it was defined.

Comment: Got it. This time the value is `((quote italic))`. Then how can I get `'italic` or `(quote italic)` again in this case? I really know little about elisp. Thanks.

Comment: In *this* case you could use `car` to obtain the first item in the list, but my guess is that this is not a sensible general approach -- I'm assuming the value isn't in a list for no reason. The customize library will doubtless provide some kind of API for this.

Comment: Aha, just didn't notice that it is still a LIST! The `defcustom` value always has an additional type declaration like *string*, and as has been seen from `describe-value`, I suppose there must be a general way to extract the `standard-value`:)

Comment: Related discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806423/how-can-i-get-a-variables-initial-value-in-elisp (the conclusions are all the same, but it might still be useful reading).